# Adding meta descriptions to thinking sphinx objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Is there any simple way for ThinkingSphinx to index some meta data keywords along with each object being indexed.

In the example below, I'am indexing the photos table here which contains photos from different locations.

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :photo, :with => :active_record do
  indexes title, description, continent, country, province, area
end
```

Now if i search for a location e.g 'bhutan', sphinx gives me all the photos and other items associated with Bhutan. But if i search for 'bhutan photos' then sphinx does not return anything since the keyword 'photo' is not indexed along with the items in the photos table.

One way for me to solve it would be to add a 'searchmeta' column in my photos table and put the descriptive keywords in that column entry. But this is very expensive because the same information will be duplicated all the rows of my photos table. I would like to know if there is any simpler way around this problem?

Comment: Kind of 'ugly', but I just remove the words (picture/photo/etc) from the query. literlly remove the words before sending the query to sphinx. Because as you note, in theory those words should just match all images anyway.

Comment: @barryhunter Thanks. That will definitely work for the photos table query. But, I have other use cases where this method will not work. E.g querying across the 'travelogues', 'reviews' 'activities' tables and presenting the consolidated results to the user.

Comment: Couldnt you just use the word to only search specific table? eg `if (contains 'photo') search_photos() elseif (contains 'reviews') search_reviews() else search_all()` sort of thing?

Comment: I'am not very comfortable with that. What if the query contains a BOOLEAN operator? If there is no other solution, i'll try looking into the thinkingsphix code and see if i can add a new configuration rule to add the table name to the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barry's suggested in the comments, you could just strip that information from the metadata keywords from queries - that might be best, but another option is you can add it directly into the index definition as a string (skipping the need to have it in the database):

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :photo, :with => :active_record do
  indexes title, description, continent, country, province, area
  indexes "'photo photos'", :as => :metadata
end
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks. In fact i'am following both Barry's and your suggestions. For queries against the photos table i strip out certain keywords from the query, but for queries against multiple tables i use the metadata indexing.

    query.gsub(/photo[a-zA-Z]*(\s+|$) | image[a-zA-Z]*(\s+|$) | |picture[a-zA-Z]*(\s+|$)/, '')